# How to enable hstore_plpython3u

Tags: postgresql, hstore, plpython

The extension hstore_plpython3u is supposed to transform hstore to/from python dict as described in the docs, but doesn't seem to work. The hstore becomes a string (no transform seems to happen). Why, and how to fix it?

> The extensions for PL/Python are called hstore_plpythonu,
> hstore_plpython2u, and hstore_plpython3u (see Section 45.1 for the
> PL/Python naming convention). If you use them, hstore values are
> mapped to Python dictionaries.
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html

Create extensions

```
create extension plpython3u;
create extension hstore_plpython3u;
```

Create a function

```
create function type(names hstore)
returns text
language plpython3u as $$
   return type(names);
$$;
```

Call function

```
select type(hstore('name','martin'));
```

returns

```
     type      
---------------
 <class 'str'>
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with this; 'If you install these transforms and specify them when creating a function, ...' from the docs.  I have no idea how you specify them when creating a function though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I think. From the `expected/hstore_plpython.out` file in `/contrib/hstore_plpython`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test1arr(val hstore[]) RETURNS int
LANGUAGE plpythonu
TRANSFORM FOR TYPE hstore
AS $$
assert(val == [{'aa': 'bb', 'cc': None}, {'dd': 'ee'}])
return len(val)
$$;
SELECT test1arr(array['aa=>bb, cc=>NULL'::hstore, 'dd=>ee']);
 test1arr
----------
        2
```